# SQL Server 2008: log autogrow cancelled by user or timed out?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I met with the following error in database log, any ideas what is wrong?

> Autogrow of file 'Foo_log' in database 'Foo' was cancelled by user or timed out after 3328 milliseconds.  Use ALTER DATABASE to set a smaller FILEGROWTH value for this file or to explicitly set a new file size.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would imagine that you have the filegrowth percentage too high.  Try reducing it down to 10%-15%. Seconds thoughts depending on the size of your Log file you should maybe change it to increase by MB size rather than %.

If your Log file is 10GB then a 10% increase is quite a lot of work for SQLServer to do.

Also, check that the disk the log file resides on has plenty of space free.

To change the AutoGrowth property:

1. Right click on the database.
2. Go to Properties.
3. Then go to the Files section.
4. Click on either the data or log autogrowth column (Click the ...)

I would also read [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315512) to help you decide on whether you need AutoGrow enabled.  Do you even need the transaction log - could you switch your Database to `simple` mode?

Comment: "Try reducing it down to 10%-15%" -- could you show me how to do it in SQL Server Management Studio 2008? I am new to this issue. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your update. Could you show me how to do it in SQL Server Management Studio 2008?

Comment: Thanks, Barry. What is your suggested option I should select? Shall I disable autogrowth? Or enable autogrowth, and select some File Growth/Max File Size parameter?

Comment: Another question is if I disable autogrowth, what is the behavior of database log, keep original size or immediately becomes smaller?

Comment: If you disable autogrowth the log file will stay at its current size.  You would have to truncate and shrink the file manually.

Comment: I really couldn't say what option you should take.  You would have to decide this based on your current situation and requirements.